# MIPS register instruction decoding

Tags: mips, decode, instruction-set

I've decode the three MIPS registries under here, but I'm not sure if I'm applying the theory correctly.
Could someone confirm my answers and perhaps shed some light on decoding the first address?

```
0010 34422345 ori $2 , $2 ,0 x2345

0018 24020007 li $2 ,7  

002c 00621021 addu $2 , $3 , $2
```

1st = opcode: 13; rs: 18; rt: 18;

2nd = I-type: opcode 8; rs 18; adress 7;

3rd = R-type: opcode 0; rs 18; rt 19; rd 18;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers look a bit off. These are my interpretations:

1) I-type

```
0x34422345
001101    00010     00010      0010001101000101  (binary)
 op (13)    rs (2)   rt (2)       imm (0x2345)

=> ori $v0,$v0,0x2345
```

---

2) I-type

```
0x24020007
001001        00000    00010    0000000000000111
 op (9=addiu)  rs (0)   rt (2)    imm (7)

=> addiu $v0,$zero,7
```

---

3) R-type

```
0x00621021
000000   00011   00010    00010    00000     100001
 op (0)   rs (3)  rt (2)   rd (2)   shift   function (33)

=> addu $v0,$v1,$v0
```

---

[Here's a list](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~isg/res/mips/opcodes) of opcode/function numbers.

Comment: Ah, but shouldn't the values $2 be 18? Referencing my book..
then again, I'm not sure about interpreting the material.

Comment: For `rs` and `rt` to be 18 in the first instruction, the instruction word would've had to to be `0x36522345`. But since it's `0x3422345` according to your question, that makes `rs` and `rt` 2 (as you can see in my breakdown of the instruction word into its individual parts).